# paint wall in real time before painting the wall

Tags: java, android, react-native, image-processing, android-augmented-reality

I have selected visual paint as my final year project.

**Abstract:**
Finding the right color for your wall can be a challenge to suit your taste. To make you free from the pain of painting and repainting, this application will give you a variety of selection of paint for your wall. Visual Painter lets you know the final look of your wall before the first drop of paint touches the wall.
Features of this respective application let you change the wall color with a single tap on the screen. The main objective of this application is to provide services in real-time.

**Problem:**
I don't know what technology will be used?
can I develop this app in react native?
is image processing and virtual reality are two different things?
where should I learn about these technology  (tutorial) any link?

Comment: your question is too broad for stackoverflow, therefore is off-topic and going to be closed shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try https://github.com/NativeVision. They have been adding newer devices to let you build XR apps for. I think you can build XR experiences for iOS, android, and Apple Vision Pro.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -1):

this is my personal opinion, but if I were you I would go with Unity3D as it has much wider support for the technologies you might use.

Comment: please use comments for things like that.